# Leer archivos con php desde servidor Linux a una carpeta compartida de Windows

Tags: php, php7, php5

Estoy ejecutando un script `php` en servidor **Centos**, donde lee información de archivos en carpeta compartida de Windows.
¿Cómo podría hacer esto? Sé que tendría que utilizarse `Samba`. Pero no tengo idea como hacerlo desde `php`.
En todo caso copiar los archivos si no es posible leerlos.

Puedo leer los archivos desde xampp local con la `funcion fopen():`

```
$fichero = fopen ('\\\\172.01.01.02\DPShare\Carpeta' . '\\' . $file , "r");
    if (!$fichero) {
        echo "Imposible abrir el fichero remoto para escritura.\n";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "Leyendo un archivo \n";
    }
```

Pero no así desde el servidor Centos. ¿Cómo podría leer o copiar archivos ejecutando script `php` en Servidor Centos y Buscando Carpeta compartida de archivos en Windows? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tienes un problema con tu script: los backslash son secuencia de escape de caracteres, debes utilizar doble backslash en la separacion entre tus directorios. De todas maneras, CentOS no es capaz de leer directorios con ese formato, debes montar el directorio con samba client. Cuidado porque los permisos de archivos y privilegios no son compatibles entre el sistema de archivos de windows y linux, podrías tener problemas de seguridad.

Comment: El codigo me funciona en windows, pero no asi en CentOs. podrias dar un ejemplo de como hacerlo como dices.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo montando la carpeta en tu servidor centos ejemplo:

## instalamos el paquete de cifs-utils

```
sudo yum install -y cifs-utils
```

## creamos la carpeta local donde vamos a agregar la ruta externa

```
mkdir /var/www/html/DPShare
```

## montamos la ruta en la carpeta local

```
mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=password,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755 //172.01.01.02/DPShare/Carpeta    /var/www/html/DPShare
```

## ejecutamos en caso de que aun no se muestre

```
mount -a
```

## para que se monte desde el inicio del so

agregamos al archivo o lo creamos `/etc/fstab` y dentro colocaremos

```
//172.01.01.02/DPShare/Carpeta    /var/www/html/DPShare   cifs  _netdev,username=username,password=password,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755,uid=500,gid=500 0 0
```

## y luego le damos

```
mount -a
```

> ahora ya podremos ver nuestra carpeta compartida como si fuese una local en la ruta `/var/www/html/DPShare`

Comment: cuando trato de ejecutar mount -t cifs ... Me da el siguiente mensaje: Host is down

Comment: ,puedes ver la documentacion con el comando `man mount.cifs` donde te dice que version utilizar dependiendo del SO, puedes agregar el flag `-o vers=3.0` o en el fstab `...,gid=500,vers=3.0`